# How to update Mat-Input Place Holder on Focus

Tags: angular-material, materialize, mat-input

I have this material input field where I would like to have a different placeholder When the user focuses the input.

When No Focus & No Value

[image]

When User Focuses it

[image]

When User Have some Value & Focuses it

[image]

Is there an event or work around in Material to achieve the same.

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput #message maxlength="256" placeholder="Your Message Goes Here">
  </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by passing a class variable to your `placeholder` property via property binding.

In your component create property variable with default value

```
myPlaceholder = 'Your Message Goes Here'
```

Assign variable to property `[placeholder]` and change to `Message` on `mat-form-field` click

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" (click)="myPlaceholder = 'Message'">
    <input matInput [placeholder]="myPlaceholder">
  </mat-form-field>
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fsbbzr?embed=1&file=app/input-overview-example.ts

Comment: Thanks that's solved my issue. Add another blur event to replace the Placeholder in case user did not type anything